# What are some good general economic journals to keep up with the literature in various fields?

Tags: reference-request, academic-graduate

I know about the American Economic Association Journal of Economic Literature (JEL), are there any other examples? By good I mean it should be at least Q1 or Q2 journal. It shouldn't also be specialized journal, I look for some journals to keep up with developments outside my specialization.

Comment: Perhaps [Journal of Economic Surveys](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/14676419)?

Comment: The [Journal of Economic Perspectives, of the American Economic Association](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/jep/about-jep) perhaps could be useful.

Comment: @RichardHardy yes that is what I look for. If you post it as an answer I will be happy to upvote it

Comment: @BakerStreet see my comment to Richard

Answer (score 3):

[Journal of Economic Surveys](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/14676419) may be a relevant journal. Here is an excerpt from their website:

> The Journal of Economic Surveys seeks to improve the communication of new ideas in economics, econometrics, economic history and business economics. It provides a means by which economists can keep abreast of recent developments beyond their immediate specialization.

Answer (score 3):

The [*Journal of Economic Perspectives*, of the American Economic Association,](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/jep/about-jep)  could be useful, it is a general economic journal.

From the website presentation:

> The journal publishes articles that will serve several goals: to
> synthesize and integrate lessons learned from active lines of economic
> research; to provide economic analysis of public policy issues; to
> encourage cross-fertilization of ideas among the fields of thinking;
> to offer readers an accessible source for state-of-the-art economic
> thinking; to suggest directions for future research [...]

The *Journal of Economic Perspectives* was [founded by Joseph Stiglitz, Carl Shapiro and Timothy Taylor  in 1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Economic_Perspectives)